# I can't scrape the rest of the articles in a real estate website using python

Tags: python, pagination, scrape

I need help to scrape all the articles in this real estate website from pages 1 through 7. It all goes well until halfway into page 2, then it stops scraping until page 7. I can't figure out why it stop and skips the articles. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm new to scraping websites.

[halfway through the second page scraping it stops here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sg2q.png)

[My code just seems to scrape certain articles and not the other ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbrF6.png)

[here is the difference between the one that can be scraped and the other that can't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqEVN.png)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv


def extract(page):
    URL = f'https://www.point2homes.com/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html?LocationGeoId=&LocationGeoAreaId=240589&Location=San%20Felipe,%20Baja%20California,%20Mexico&page={page}'
    headers = { 'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36',}
    # Here the user agent is for Edge browser on windows 10. You can find your browser user agent from the above given link.
    r = requests.get(url=URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    listing = soup.findAll('article')
    with open('housing.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf8', newline= '') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        header = ['Address', 'Beds', 'Baths', 'Size', 'Area', 'Acres', 'Price', 'Agent', 'Firm']
        thewriter.writerow(header)
        for ls in listing:
            #print(ls)
            try:
              address = ls.find('div', class_="address-container").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
              address = ("Not Found *")
              print(address)
            try:
              beds = ls.find('li', class_="ic-beds").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
              beds = ("Data Not Logged")
            try:
              baths = ls.find('li', class_="ic-baths").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
              baths = ("Data not logged")
            try:
              size = ls.find('li', class_="ic-sqft").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
              size = ("Data not logged")
            try:
              acre = ls.find('li', class_="ic-lotsize").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
              acre = ("Data not found")
            area = ls.find('li', class_="property-type ic-proptype").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            price = ls.find('span', class_="green").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            try:
              agent = ls.find('div', class_="agent-name").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
              agent = ("not found x")
              print(agent)
            firmstr = ls.find('div', class_="agent-company")
            firm = ''
            if firmstr is not None:
              spl_word = '>'
              sagent = str(firmstr)
              p1 = sagent.split(spl_word, 1)
              p2 = p1[1]
              res = p2.split('<', 1)
              resf = res[0]
              cleanres = resf.strip().replace('\n', '')
              firm = cleanres
              r_list =[address, beds, baths, size, area, acre, price, agent, firm]
              thewriter.writerow(r_list)
              print(r_list)
for i in range(1, 7):
    print(f'Getting page {i}...')
    c = extract(i)
    #sleep
    r_result = transform(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. See below for a suggested refactored version (with some comments to help you understand what is being done). First, let me address some of the main problems:

- `for i in range(1, 7):`. You never reach page 7. Check [`ranges`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges), the `stop` integer is not included in the sequence.
- `with open('housing.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf8', newline= '') as f:`. You are using `mode='w'`, which means: "open for writing, truncating the file first". I.e. on each iteration, you are deleting all the previous rows and writing new ones in the file. See [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You are looking for `a`, meaning: "open for writing, appending to the end of file if it exists". Even then you should do something about `header`. As is, you would be adding the header (6) 7 times; we need it only for the first row.
- The next bit seems to cause most confusion:

```
            try:
              agent = ls.find('div', class_="agent-name").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
              agent = ("not found x")
              print(agent)
            firmstr = ls.find('div', class_="agent-company")
            firm = ''
            if firmstr is not None:
              # ... some lines ...
              r_list =[address, beds, baths, size, area, acre, price, agent, firm]
              thewriter.writerow(r_list)
              print(r_list)
```

- From page 2 onwards, you get an awful lot of `not found x` prints. You seem to take this as a sign that no data has been found. But the only thing this is saying, is that the page is not showing an *agent* for a particular listing. It was retrieving the other info (`address`, `baths`, etc.) just fine. Now, notice however that you have nested the line `thewriter.writerow(r_list)` inside the `if`-statement that checks if `firmstr` has a value. This means that whenever your code cannot find a firm, it will simply skip the entire listing! This is a problem, as listings halfway through page 2 stop having either an agent or a firm. E.g. from that point onwards, you are never telling the code to write anything other than the header.
- A last more general advice is to try to find ways to keep your functions small and to avoid repetitive code. E.g. instead of all your `try / except` statements, try to group the items that need the same kind of processing, and work with the actual result from a `bs4` function call (e.g. respond to potential `None`). Finally, ideally, a function does just one thing.

---

**Suggested refactored version**.

There is plenty in here that can still be optimized either in accordance with the advice just mentioned or because there are better methods to begin with. So, by all means have a go at that!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
from tqdm import tqdm
import math

BASE = 'https://www.point2homes.com/'
HEADERS = { 'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 
           'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36',}

PARAMS = {'LocationGeoAreaId': '240589',
          'Location': 'San Felipe, Baja California, Mexico',
          'page': None}

dict_pages = {'pages': None}

def extract(page = 1):
    '''
    Extract `listings` in `soup` for each page
    '''
    # (prep for) GET request
    url = f'{BASE}/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html'
    params = PARAMS.copy()
    params['page'] = page
    r = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=HEADERS)
    
    # get listings per page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    
    # get indication pages; each page has max. 24 entries
    if page == 1:
        entries = int(soup.find('div', class_='pager_title_section')\
                      .get_text().split()[0])
        max_entries_per_page = 24
        dict_pages['pages'] = math.ceil(entries/max_entries_per_page)
    
    # progress prints
    print(f'Getting page {page} of {dict_pages["pages"]}. Processing data...', 
          end='\n')
    
    listings = soup.findAll('article')
    # check if page contains a `next` elem
    if soup.find('a', class_='pager-next'):
        _next = page + 1
        return listings, _next
    return listings, None

def extract_agent(href_listing):
    '''
    Extracts agent, firm as `list`. Used if such info not available on main page.
    '''
    # GET request, soup, extract agent, firm (firm may be `None`)
    r = requests.get(url=f'{BASE}{href_listing}', headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    agent = soup.find('div', class_='agent-details-top').div.get_text(strip=True)
    firm = soup.find('div', class_='agent-details-top').p
    if firm:
        firm = firm.get_text(strip=True)
    return [agent, firm]

def transform(ls):
    '''
    Returns a `list` ('r_list'), i.e. a "row" to be passed to func `writer`.
    '''
    # initialize list
    r_list = list()
    
    # get `address` (use `get_text(strip=True)` instead of
    # `.text.replace('\n', "").strip()` here and elsewhere)
    address = ls.find('div', class_='address-container').get_text(strip=True)
    r_list.append(address)
    
    # get `beds, baths, size, area, acres`
    labels = ['Beds?', 'Baths?', 'Sqft', 'property-type ic-proptype', 'Lot Size']
    
    for label in labels:
        if label != 'property-type ic-proptype':
            label_item = ls.find('li', {'data-label': re.compile(label)})
            if label_item:
                # the actual measurement will be first elem in split 
                # on `<strong>`, replace ',' with '' to get numeric
                label_item = label_item.strong.get_text(strip=True).split()[0]\
                    .replace(',','')
                r_list.append(label_item)
            else:
                # info not found
                r_list.append(None)
        else:
            # handle `area` differently
            area = ls.find('li', class_='property-type ic-proptype')\
                          .get_text(strip=True)
            r_list.append(area)
    
    # get `price`, extract only part with digits, and replace ',' with ''
    # I.e. *these* listings at least are *all* in "USD"
    price = re.search(r'\d+,\d+', ls.find('div', class_='price')\
              ['data-price']).group().replace(',','')
    r_list.append(price)
    
    # alternative for `price`, if you just want whole string: 
        # r_list.append(ls.find('div', class_='price')['data-price'])
    # or maybe try to split `amount` and `currency` in diff columns
    
    # get `agent, firm`
    agents = ['agent-name', 'agent-(?=item-company|company)']
    
    for agent in agents:
        agent_item = ls.find('div', {'class': re.compile(agent)})
        if agent_item:
            agent_item = agent_item.get_text(strip=True)
            r_list.append(agent_item)
            
    # numerous listings only have `agent, firm` on the actual listing page
    if len(r_list) == 7:
        # if `True`, nothing was added, so get `href` and check listing page
        href_listing = ls.select_one('a[href]')['href']
        r_list.extend(extract_agent(href_listing))

    return r_list

def writer(listings, add_header = False):
    '''
    Writes data per listing captured in `r_list` as single rows to csv file.
    '''
    fname = 'housing.csv'
    
    # N.B. mode should be `a` (append); 
    # with `w` you would overwrite the file each time
    with open(file = fname, mode = 'a', encoding = 'utf8', newline= '') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        
        # only add the header at the start
        if add_header == True:
            header = ['Address', 'Beds', 'Baths', 'Size', 'Area', 'Acres', 
                      'Price', 'Agent', 'Firm']
            thewriter.writerow(header)
            
        # get `row` per listing and append to csv
        for ls in tqdm(listings):
            r_list = transform(ls)
            thewriter.writerow(r_list)
    if not _next:
        print(f'\n{fname} created')
    return _next

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get listings per page. We'll stop after p. 7, where `_next` == `None`
    listings, _next = extract()
    _next = writer(listings, add_header=True)
    while _next:
        listings, _next = extract(_next)
        _next = writer(listings)
```

Prints:

```
Getting page 1 of 7. Processing data...
100%|██████████| 24/24 [00:00<00:00, 512.09it/s]
Getting page 2 of 7. Processing data...
100%|██████████| 24/24 [00:05<00:00,  4.34it/s]
Getting page 3 of 7. Processing data...
100%|██████████| 24/24 [00:17<00:00,  1.37it/s]
Getting page 4 of 7. Processing data...
100%|██████████| 24/24 [00:15<00:00,  1.58it/s]
Getting page 5 of 7. Processing data...
100%|██████████| 24/24 [00:15<00:00,  1.53it/s]
Getting page 6 of 7. Processing data...
100%|██████████| 24/24 [00:14<00:00,  1.67it/s]
Getting page 7 of 7. Processing data...
100%|██████████| 19/19 [00:12<00:00,  1.55it/s]
housing.csv created

# notice the later pages are slower; this is because we are fetching
# the agent / firm data from individual listing pages
```

Result csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')

print(df.iloc[0])

Address    El Dorado Ranch 7200-13-13, San Felipe, Baja C...
Beds                                                     3.0
Baths                                                    2.0
Size                                                  1900.0
Area                                             Residential
Acres                                                  0.319
Price                                                 299800
Agent                             Darryl & Michelle McDonogh
Firm                                    Baja Sun Real Estate
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you so much. Your solution is very efficent. This will help me alot to improve. May god bless you and may gods peace be upon you.